# Does Apple silicon hardware support USB tethering in macOS recovery mode?

Tags: macos, recovery, tethering, apple-silicon, intel

After updating my Intel MBP to macOS 12.5, I got locked out. When trying to reset the password in the recovery mode (power+cmd+r), USB tethering to my iPhone did not work and I had to use my iPhone as a hotspot through Wi-Fi. Then I was able to set a new password using my Apple ID.

I am now wondering if Apple silicon MBPs can use USB tethering in the recovery mode.

Comment: "Mx PowerBooks" - Possible typo and you mean MacBooks?

Comment: Yes thank you agarza.  New M1/2 MacBooks

Comment: USB tethering is slower than a WiFi hotspot. Why was that your first choice?

Comment: Yes.  I do not use Wireless tech Wi-Fi/ Bluetooth when dealing with resetting passwords, especially involving the Apple ID creds..   have been hacked  several times before just FYI

Answer (score 2):

M1 Macs cannot use USB tethering to provide a network while in Recovery Mode. This is the same as your experience on an Intel Mac.

The recoveryOS UI only presents options for connecting to WiFi, or wired Ethernet networks (with the addition of a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adaptor for MacBooks). The USB tethering functionality is contained in the Network Preferences pane under a normal boot of macOS. That has the option to manage the full gamut of network hardware, such as WiFi, USB, or Thunderbolt Bridges.

Comment: Select a Wi-Fi network from the menu or attach a network cable to proceed…. Is what the recovery screen shows.  The network cable must be Ethernet for the desktop macs.   Thanks for the info!

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the cable option. But with a new MBP with no TB to Ethernet dongle to hand I must admit it was easy to forget. Don't forget to mark the answer as useful if indeed it was...